# How can i get json array string from a soap web service method with ios Swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, soap

How can i get data below with swift 3 for my ios app?

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[ { "Hotel_id": 1, "Hotel_Name": "Sherwood Breezes Resort", "Company_id": 1 }, { "Hotel_id": 2, "Hotel_Name": "Sherwood Dreams Resort", "Company_id": 1 }, { "Hotel_id": 3, "Hotel_Name": "TUI Sensimar Resort", "Company_id": 1 }, { "Hotel_id": 4, "Hotel_Name": "Sherwood Greenwood Resort", "Company_id": 1 }, { "Hotel_id": 5, "Hotel_Name": "Sherwood Club Kemer", "Company_id": 1 }, { "Hotel_id": 6, "Hotel_Name": "Sherwood Prize Hotel", "Company_id": 1 } ]
</string>
```

I need to get this data as a json array and convert it to an array.

Comment: This is the return string? Why it's surrounded by html tag

Comment: Use `(NS)XMLParser` to retrieve the JSON inside the tags. Then use `(NS)JSONSerialization` to retrieve your array of dictionaries.

Comment: Could you give an example as an aswer how to do that?

Comment: Famming Ning Yes this is a return string and i have no idea about your question but i used that web method with ksoap2 in my android app it works fine. unless i dont know how to use it in ios side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to remove the html tags in the string.You only need the json part.

```
let yourString = yourString .replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)
```

Then parse it into JSON. Don't forget to handle unwrap

```
let data = yourString.data(using: .utf8)

do{
    let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [Any]
    //You can start looping though the array from this point.
    let firstHotel = jsonArray?[0] as? [String: Any]
    let Hotel_id = firstHotel?["Hotel_id"] as? Int
    let Hotel_Name = firstHotel?["Hotel_Name"] as? String
    let Company_id = firstHotel?["Company_id"] as? Int
}catch let error{

}
```

Comment: Ok thank you Fangming Ning i got that part but i can't get this return string in swift that is my main problem. How can i get this string in swift? how can i do the soap web servise connection and sent parameters to the webmethod?

Comment: @arzucaki What is the url and parameters?